# How to delete a dynamically generated entry in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to automate a test where I add particular details which are nicely stored in table(which initially was empty), I verify those details and then I delete those details from the table. This is repeated over a period of time.

I have been able to implement this till verification, but the problem arises when I try to delete the entries from table. The test is successfully executed once, but when new details are added again, the indexes of table entries changes and hence the selenium IDE is not being able to find the entries based on locator defined earlier.

Is it possible to find the dynamically generated indexes of table and then delete those entries?